# use google drive api get children without trash

Tags: java, google-drive-api

How can I get a folder's children files without the deleted files in trash, my code as follow:

```
 Children children = service.children();
 Drive.Children.List request = children.list("root");
  do
  {
    try
       {
          ChildList cList = request.execute();
          for (ChildReference cr : cList.getItems())
           {
              File file = service.files().get(cr.getId())   .execute();
              System.out.println(file.getTitle() + "--"+ file.getMimeType());
           }
        request.setPageToken(cList.getNextPageToken());
       }
   catch (IOException e)
      {
          System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
          request.setPageToken(null);
      }
 } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `trashed = false` query when listing:

```
drive.files().list().setQ("trashed = false").execute();
```

More querying options are on https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

Comment: I can't find any execute function :/ can you give me the link to lib that you used

Answer (score 15):

If you have a query with ***multiple conditions***, like you want to get ROOT's files and folder, and also don't want to get the trashed files. Then below query will helpful
"'root' in parents and trashed=false"

```
  request.setQ("'root' in parents and trashed=false").execute();
```